# White Screen of Death - wp-admin

Tags: php, wp-admin, errors

I am having a strange issue with the `wp-admin` page of a WordPress site.

I have enabled errors and receive the following warning when requesting `/wp-admin/`:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at wp-config.php:1) in wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1216

I have checked the files and do not have any whitespace at the beginning of the wp-config file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install a new theme or plugin when this started?  What triggered the white screen?

Comment: It's more likely you've got whitespace at the end of a file (probably a plugin or a theme file). One way to avoid this is to [not use PHP's `?>` closing tags at the end of a file](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#remove-trailing-spaces) -- they're unnecessary anyway.

Comment: nope, no new themes or plugins, a new post was posted on 15th May.

Comment: there are no ?> at the end of the files, although there is a carriage return

Answer (score 2):

I'd comment on [Fayaz's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/305553/122392), but I don't have enough reputation to comment. So here's my additional advice:

Along with checking hidden white space characters in `wp-config.php` file and elsewhere, I'd recommend you to temporarily disable all plugins and switch to the default WordPress Theme (e.g. `Twenty Seventeen Theme`). Then check if you still have the error.

If error / warning is still shown after doing the above, then definitely it's coming from core files, so follow Fayaz's instruction on removing whitespace, by creating new `wp-config.php` file.

However, if no error / warning is shown after doing the above, then it's not coming from `wp-config.php`, rather from your theme or a plugin. In this case, enable the theme & plugins one by one & check which one causes the error.

You say you didn't install new Theme / Plugin, but it's possible that the error was there forever & only now it's showing after enabling PHP error reporting.

> *Note:* It's also a good idea to clear browser cache before you do this test. Sometimes browsers show output from older sessions & that may confuse you while you test.

Comment: Or, perhaps a plugin was updated ;)

Answer (score 1):

This means, somewhere there is some output coming from your `wp-config.php` file.

Or, may be there is space or carriage return before `<?php` tag

Or, may be there is space or carriage return after `?>` tag.

Or, may be even a minor PHP syntax error that's closing the `?>` without you intending it.

It'll be Clear if you check the PHP error logs on your server.

---

> **Note-1:** if whitespace is difficult to find, create a new file from scratch and rename the old file as backup. Sometimes some unicode whitespace characters are not shown within the editors properly, even though it's there.

---

> **Note-2:** Whitespace may've come from Theme/Plugin updates as well, so you better check & make sure those are OK too.

Answer (score -1):

So.... tried all of the above and nothing worked.

So i ended up restoring all of the core Wordpress files which seems to have fixed the issue.

Thanks for your thoughts anyway